# how to dynamically allocate 2d array by one row at a time where column is known in c/c++

Tags: c++, c, arrays

I want to allocate a 2d array(in C or C++) where row is unknown but column is known.I do not want to allocate my row n size first because when i want an input ,**the array's first row will allocate with known column size->then i take my input-> put it in my array's row 1 .Then again if i  want an input, the array's second row will allocate with known column size->then i take my input-> put it in my array's row 2**. this process will run for an unknown number of rows and i want to preserve all my input for further processing.When i press Enter button twice the input will stop and the next process will begin which is not a concern here.What should i do about this or is this possible at all in C or C++ ?Giving me full functional code will be very helpful because i have a very little knowledge about pointer or array or other things that is related to this problem's solution.

Comment: In C++ use a `std::vector`.

Comment: please provide a complete code if possible

Comment: Here is all that you may need..http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/

Comment: @user3257218 -1 for asking others to do your work for you. That's not what SO is for.

Comment: "C or C++" is not a language. These are two languages, and the answer is different for each one. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to using `realloc`, you can use `malloc` to allocate rows one-at-a-time. The following provides for a dynamically growing array with fixed columns of `ARRAY_WIDTH`. Input for each row expects `ARRAY_WIDTH` values. Example:

```
#define ARRAY_WIDTH 10

/* psuedo code for array of ints with fixed columns = ARRAY_WIDTH */

int *array[ARRAY_WIDTH];
int idx = 0;
int j = 0;

/* get your input with getline in a while loop */
{
        array[idx] = malloc (sizeof (array));  /* allocate fixed width */

        /* assign values to array  0 <= values < ARRAY_WIDTH */
        for (j = 0, ptr = buffer; j < ARRAY_WIDTH; j++, ptr++)
            array [idx][j] = /* your data */;

        idx++;
}

int nrows = idx;
```